# How to sideload iOS App from Visual Studio (Windows) on a iPhone?

Tags: ios, deployment, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I already got a blank app running from Visual Studio For Mac. (Im using this free test developer account from apple)

But now I have an App for UWP, Andriod and iOS on Visual Studio 2017 with Windows. But I dont now how to set up my project to deploy it on my iPhone. Remote simulating it on a Mac is not the problem.

Is it even possible? I cant find any guide for that...

Comment: You can run all version in Visual studio for Windows simultaneously by connecting Your mac with visual studio of a Windows computer. In order to deploy your app in physical iPhone, you can do that only from your mac.

Comment: I connected my Mac already with VS2017 und debugging in a simulator works. But i can choose my iPhone when its plugged in my Mac. But for this it seems that I have set my Apple Developer ID in the Project. But I can not chose this setting.

Comment: Is device provisioning ready? please refer to [Device Provisioning for Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/)

Comment: How can I test if it is ready? I can load from my Mac a app to my phone.